# Consulta dentro de método, me repite los datos en todas las filas

Tags: mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-4

no se a que se deba que al solicitar una vista de la BD, y llamarla desde un método, esta me trae el número correcto de filas, pero en todas muestra los datos de la primer coincidencia encontrada, como que no se llena el listado avanzando la consulta. Este es el método utilizado:

```
        public ActionResult Tutorados(int id = 0)
    {
        int page = 1;
        int pageSize = 30;
        string sort = "Id";
        string sortdir = "DESC";
        var _records = new PagedList<vTutoradosDeGrupos_Coordinador>();
        ViewBag.filter = id;
        using (TutoriasEntities dbTutorias = new TutoriasEntities())
        {
            _records.Content = dbTutorias.vTutoradosDeGrupos_Coordinador 
                            .Where(x => x.id.Equals(id))
                            .OrderBy(sort + " " + sortdir)
                            .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
                            .Take(pageSize)
                            .ToList();
        }
        _records.CurrentPage = page;
        _records.PageSize = pageSize;
        return View(_records);
    }
```

Gracias por el apoyo.

PD. La consulta que apunta a una vista, en SQL server muestra la información.

Comment: Estas utilizando el paquete nuget `PagedList.mvc`?

Comment: Saludos Rafael, No se como saber si lo uso..., pero te comento uso listados con similar estructura en otras vistas llamas desde métodos y están funcionando correctamente, mostrándome toda la información filtrada, solo con este método no se que suceda en especial.

Answer (score 0):

Desconozco por que razón, pero re-hice la vista, elimine la BD del proyecto y la agregue, y se soluciono.